# Sharing data between web server(s) and worker server(s)

Tags: networking, redis, webserver

I'm currently developing an application from the ground up that requires some form of communication between the user-facing web servers, and the backend (hidden) worker servers that communicate with endpoint devices. I've diagrammed the whole environment below:
[image]

**My question is, what is the best way (industry way, perhaps?) to send requests from the web servers to the worker servers with a request-response structure?** My current implementation (as recommended by other answers) uses a REDIS message broker (although RabbitMQ and other solutions seem identical to how I am using it) to achieve this communication. Downside is, it's not request-response oriented.

Here is a sample scenario:

1. User A clicks a "PING Device E" button on the website
2. Webserver 1 receives this as an HTTP request. Webserver 1 knows Device E is connected to Worker Server 2 (knowing this is not a problem), and thus sends a message to Worker Server 2, telling it to send the PING request to Device E.
3. Device E responds to Worker Server 2 with "PONG". Worker Server 2 then completes the request from Web Server 1, telling it that it received "PONG".
4. Web Server 1 completes the initial HTTP request, telling the user the device responded with "PONG"